# Child routes are not allowed for "/". Use "..." on the parent's route path

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have a parent page kms.html which is loading with router-outlet which loads Login page and my landing page based on login I implemented routing ... now after routing to my landing page which again have router-outlet,  in landing component if I write

```
@RouteConfig([

        { path: '/kms/test', name:'Test', component: testComponent }
    ])
```

it is throwing an error as Child routes are not allowed for `/kms`. Use `...` on the parent's route path.

If I remove that `@RouteConfig` part its working fine, but I cannot perform child routing.

Any Clues on this?

Answer (score 2):

Define the parent's route config like so:

```
{ path: '/kms/...', component: XXXComponent, as: 'Kms?' }
```

And in your child's route config only put it like this:

```
{ path: '/test', name:'Test', component: testComponent }
```